# Flutter contact loading takes so much time

Tags: flutter

I want to load all phone contact. For loading contact I am using [contact_service](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/contacts_service) package. But this takes so much time almost 5-12 sec. In native Android it takes almost no time. Is there any alternative solution for this problem?

**My code:**

```
getContacts() async{
  var contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();

  setState(() {
    _contacts = contacts;
  }

}
```

Comment: Make an issue on the github's package instead

Comment: https://github.com/clovisnicolas/flutter_contacts/issues/32

Comment: got no solution

Comment: it's happened on native also if you are reading it in the wrong way, especially when the phone contact is large. if only 10 to hundreds, its easy feat to load it all in once, but if the phone contact has more than thousand, its a bit nightmare if you call it in one call. You have to use Stream for it, and seamlessly updates the UI one by one after the Stream returns a contact detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can write in this way

```
getContacts() async{
  var contacts;
  await ContactsService.getContacts().then((data){
    setState((){
      contacts = data;
    });
  });;
}
```

Comment: Here it seems the answer doesn't address the problem specified. The answer shows us to get the contacts from ContactService which is present in the library documentation itself. Please try to answer about what can be done to reduce the time to load the contacts. example: use of paging,indexing etc.